# How can I parse dates in this HTML javascript page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if i could get some help on trying to get this page to accept an input, then spit out whether or not it was a valid input or not.

So far I have written this.

```
<html>

<head>
   <title>JavaScript Date Strings</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsdatestrings.css" />

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="title">JavaScript Popup and Validation</h1>

<img class="popup-btn" src="death.jpg" />

<p>Das Datum (mm/dd/yyyy): <input id = "date" type="text" name="date"></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").blur(function(){
    var x = $("#date").val();
    $("#test").html(x);
  });
});
</script>

<p id="test">HERRO!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

I am not very sure how to get it and work with it. I know the input is working but I need to get something like 09281990 and it should  give me something like 09/28/1990 and if I set it to yyyy-mm-dd then it should read it as invalid unless i put 19900928.

Any help would be welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input").blur(function(){
        var x = $("#date").val();
var day = x.substring(0,2);
var month = x.substring(2,4);
var year = x.substring(4,8);
     re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;

        if(!(day+'/'+month+'/'+year).match(re)) {
          alert("Invalid date format: " + day+'/'+month+'/'+year);  
        }else{

        $("#test").html(day+'/'+month+'/'+year);
    }  });
    });



    Try this..
```

Comment: I tried it out and it works but I don't want to just settle for, it works thank you, I want to see if I could get a bit of an explanation so that way I understand it and I don't waste people's time just asking dumb questions.

Comment: Have a look Regular Expression tutorial
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: For now I seem to have the program working but one thing I wanted to do now is to give the user the option to chose formats like if I don't like the one you gave me, I can change it to yyyy/mm/dd. I would like to give it a whack on my own but what would you recommend? Switch statement? If else? etc....

Comment: Give d user a listbox option where he can select d format based on d format selected u sub-string the text box value...

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js library: http://momentjs.com/
It knows how to parse dates from lots of different formats.

And it also has a method moment(date).isValid() which shows you if the object you are passing was successfully parsed to date.

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY") // will parse your date from MM-DD-YYYY format;
moment("not a real date").isValid(); // false
```